# Selenium UI tests too slow on Jenkins on Firefox (with xvfb)

Tags: performance, firefox, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, configuration

I am running Selenium UI tests on Jenkins using Firefox driver, and they are executing extremely slow as compared to local execution. Specifically, it is taking almost 4 times the time it takes to run locally. That's too inefficient.

Locally I run it on Windows or Mac, not Linux. The Jenkins job, however runs on Linux.

The details of the environment is below:

- Jenkins (running on Linux on a virtual machine)
- Xvfb for emulating browser (no display attached to the VM)
- Firefox 38
- Java 8

I am not sure if a Jenkins configuration or anything else would make it faster. Could it be the VM causing it? Everything is running just fine, but it's the slowness that's causing the inefficiency.

Any ideas to improve the performance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be hard to suggest anything to improve performance without knowing the specs you've allowed for your VM or what the scripts look like that you're running. My educated guess is that your VM has too little RAM.

Have you tried running the top command while your tests are running to see if cpu or RAM are suffering?

Comment: Thanks @NaviSaysListen. Yes, I did run the top command and did not notice anything bad with the resources. I have added a snapshot of the machine's stats to the main post.

Comment: Just a couple more questions: When you run these tests locally, is it on a Windows machine? And is there a proxy that your local machine is configured to handle that the linux VM is not?

Comment: I run it on both Windows and Mac locally. Not Linux (so that's certainly a difference). The tests run directly on Firefox (without xvfb). There is no proxy, it's direct access.

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to say what could be happening, then. Thanks for including more information. It's a strange issue to me, because tests I run headlessly seem to always run faster, not slower! Hopefully somebody else has run into this and can help you. Some final suggestions: try creating a new VM that mirrors the one you're using, and also try messing with Selenium and Firefox versions. There could be some compatibility problems.

Comment: Thanks @NaviSaysListen. If there were compatibility problems, wouldn't that have surfaced on local runs too? Just a quick question -- is there anything on the Jenkins configuration that needs to be turned on or off that might cause a difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83774/discussion-between-navisayslisten-and-naspras).

Comment: Hey @naspras. Did you happen to come across a solution here? I'm seeing similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was essentially rooted into the disk IO of the Jenkins slave that was running the tests. The local machines (Mac or Windows) are very fast and usually have SSDs as the disk type. Updating the Jenkins slave to something that has better hardware resources and faster disk IO solved the problem.

Comment: did you notice any performance downsides with the xvfb regardless? Even the slightest ones.